# Cardboard SDK for IOS how to disable distortion correction?

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

How can I disable distortion correction in an app for IOS using Cardboard SDK?

In some cases, it is necessary to speed up an app.

Answer (score 0):

try this：
XRSetting.load（“cardboard”）
XRSetting.enabled=false